# Expected feature vector size using Inception-v2 in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I wish to extract feature vectors for areas of interest in object detection. I am using Faster RCNN & Inception-v2, essentially following [this tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/v1.13.0/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) but I've added `detection_features` as a key.

I was under the impression that the feature vector was the output of the CNN before it goes on to be classified. From looking at table 1 in the [Inception-v2 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00567v3.pdf), I expected this to be of size 1x1x1000. However, the size of `output_dict['detection_features'][0]` in my code is 4x4x1024, which confuses me as it seems that is not a vector size that appears in any step of Inception-v2.

Any pointers as to why the sizes do not match would be greatly appreciated, I'm concerned I may have misunderstood something but I can't find much documentation on the feature vector in Tensorflow's object detection.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific number of units per layer isn't an architectural law; a network following the Inception V2 architecture is foremost a matter of the flow of information. Your situation looks fine. The creator of Keras once wrote that using units in multiples of 8 may provide a slight computational advantage, so your last layer units is perhaps slightly better than the paper's. As for the `4,4` bit, that can be a result of the input dimensions. This is why there is a minimum possible input size (otherwise some operations wouldn't have any pixels to work with). A larger input (image) following the same Inception V2 *procedure* will result in larger output dimensions. That's fine, it just means a straight flattening (between cnn and classifier) results in more units, or, alternatively, global pooling discards more information.

In summary: what you've done is perfectly fine. An architecture is a matter of graph operations, whereas specific implementations (dimensions within the network) are a matter of application.

**Edit: a more thorough explanation**
Convolutional layers are defined by their kernel shape and the number of units (the number of kernels). If an architecture uses a convolutional layer with a (3,3) matrix kernel, it will apply this regardless of the size of content provided to it (at least as large as the kernel). So if a network architecture like VGG [(diagram)](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-e657c195fc2696c7d5fc0b1e3682fde6) calls for a certain number of convolutional layers with (3,3) kernels followed by a (2,2) pooling layer, then it really doesn't matter if you make your network input shape (299,299,3) or (32,32,32). The same operations will be performed on the inputs, just a different number of times along the axes (including, of course, the last axis, which is the number of units, which is the number of unique kernels), resulting in a different output shape.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks, I think I understand. I'd always thought NNs required a fixed input size, but this is only for things like fully connected layers, whereas Inception (until its linear layer) only uses convolutions & pooling which is agnostic to size. So because my input is about 4 times larger and wider than what the 'standard' implementation would take, it's not reduced to 1x1? Would the vector at 1,1 represent the top left of the image and 4,4 the lower right?

Comment: I don't mean to confuse you; your original understanding is correct: NNs require a fixed input size. However, you can make it whatever you want. As a result, larger inputs mean larger outputs, although (4,4,units) rather than (1,1,units) doesn't mean the input was 4 times larger; it depends on the operations within the network. Here, I made this for you: [kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/kwisatzhaderach/inceptions-v3-with-various-input-shapes). The main point is that network architectures are procedures; dimensions are up to you and your application's needs.

Comment: With regard to your question about what the output represents... A lot of people think it works like that; it's frequently referred to as a "feature map," but have a look at some output for yourself: there's seldom anything cartographic about it. The reality is that it's information-laden encoding, scarcely intelligible to humans. But that's ok! Just because it doesn't technically look like a "feature map" doesn't mean you can't treat it like one, if your targets have spatial dependence---the richly encoded information can carry that information just as well.

Comment: Ok, that makes perfect sense, and thank you so much for the kaggle, that is very useful and makes it super clear. I still can't help but feel there would be some slight tendency for feature maps to better represent the area around its position, especially for larger inputs. But, as you suggest, I am going to try it out myself and expect to find it is as you say and the maps are so abstracted that position is no longer of much relevance.

Thanks so much for taking the time to answer, it has been incredibly helpful :)

Comment: Sure thing, glad it makes sense :) Your intuition is surely right, the output pixels are spatially related to the input ones, based on the conv/pooling process. It's just that by the time it reaches the output, so many operations have been performed that (unless it were mandated by training) the output is more of a information-slurry. I'm currently working on a large visualization project that will make this explorable.